# Find by conditions on associated model in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.2

I have two tables `orders` and `sub_orders`.
Their association is

```
$orders->hasMany('SubOrders', [
   'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
]);
```

Both tables have `invoice_no` and `sub_invoice` columns in `orders` and `sub_orders` respectively.

I have to find records from `orders` table containing associated `sub_orders` where `$trackingId` will match either `Orders.invoice_no` or `SubOrders.sub_invoice`

```
$findOrder = $this->Orders->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
      'OR' => [
         'Orders.invoice_no' => $trackingId,
         'SubOrders.sub_invoice' => $trackingId
       ]
     ],
     'contain' => [
        'SubOrders'
     ]
  ]);
```

But this gives error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SubOrders.sub_invoice' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: add conditions to SubOrders model.

Comment: `$trackingId` will match either from `Orders` or from `SubOrders`. can't use `and` because condition for both will be never satisfied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing the query like this:

```
$findOrder = $this->Orders->find()
->where(['Orders.invoice_no' => $trackingId])
->contain(['SubOrders' => function ($q) use ($trackingId) {
   return $q

        ->where(['SubOrders.sub_invoice' => $trackingId]);
}
]);
```

Comment: Getting undefined variable "$trackingId", for line  "where(['SubOrders.sub_invoice' => $trackingId]);"

Comment: bikash.bitz - That's because this example was using a variable they were setting already.

Comment: I tried your solution, At line number 2(in where condition) $trackingId is defined but In line number 5 getting error $trackingId is not defined.

Comment: change it from **function ($q)** to **function ($q) use ($trackingId)**

Comment: How to achieve the same for other associations. Let's consider I have a model Packages which is associated with orders. I want to search all the 3 table for the existing of the $trackingId (Condition for all 3 models are in OR).

Comment: Here is my questions link if you like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473939/use-or-conditions-on-associated-model-in-cakephp-3