# Find by associated data on paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

I have two:
`Providers` and `Purchasetopay` with the following association:

```
$Providers->hasMany('Purchasetopay', [
   'foreignKey' => 'providers_id'
]);
```

and I also have the following action:

```
public function fornecedores(){

        $Providers = TableRegistry::get('Providers');

        $pesquisar = $this->request->query('pesquisar');

        if(!empty($pesquisar)){
            $this->paginate = [
                'conditions' => 
                            [ 'OR' => 
                                ['Providers.cnpj' => $pesquisar,
                                 'Providers.corporatename LIKE' => '%'.$pesquisar.'%',
                                ]                              
                            ]
                         ];
        }

        $query = $Providers->find()->contain(['Telephones','Purchasetopay'=>['SupplierNotes']]);
        $providers = $this->paginate($query);
        $this->set(compact('providers'));

    }
```

I need to add Purchasetopay field to `OR` conditions. How?
I saw this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39559315/11239369
However, I don't know how to adapt my code to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  orWhere/andWhere as below  :

```
$query = $Providers->find()
          ->contain(['Telephones','Purchasetopay'=>['SupplierNotes']])
          ->where( ['Providers.cnpj' => $pesquisar])
          ->orWhere(['Providers.corporatename LIKE' => '%'.$pesquisar.'%' ]);
```